# How to create "Add to my List"?

Tags: 7

I have a movie site and I want users to be able to add movies (node) to their list by visiting the movie and it should have a link saying "Add to my list". When they are about to add to their list it should have a selection box with options like watching, completed, on-hold etc...

An example site http://myanimelist.net/anime.php?id=269 you can see when you click their "Add to my List" it gives some more options like status, eps seen, score

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag), as it provides this functionality for users upon install. The [Nodequeue module](http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue) is intended for admin-configured lists.

Comment: I'm using the flag module but I don't know how to make a drop down list to give more options such as completed, ongoing, on-hold.

Answer (score 0):

Use the nodequeue module http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue: The Nodequeue module allows users to collect nodes in an arbitrarily ordered list. The order in the list can be used for a any purpose, such as...A user’s favorite music albums or the flag list module http://drupal.org/project/flag_lists